# Why Rocket validations are not executing on Json?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I have the following code where I use the [Rocket](https://github.com/rwf2/Rocket) validations:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, FromForm)]
pub struct CreateUserDto<'r> {
    #[field(validate = email_validation())]
    email: &'r str,
    password: &'r str,
}

fn email_validation(email: &str) -> Result<()> {
    let re: Regex = Regex::new(r"^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$").unwrap();

    if !re.is_match(email) {
        Err(Error::validation("invalid email address"))?;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

In that code I am trying to validate the email field according to a given regex. For some reason the `email_validation` function is never called.

Any idea why? I was following the Rocket documentation as seen here: https://api.rocket.rs/master/rocket/form/validate/#custom-validation

I also tried to add the built-in validation:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, FromForm)]
pub struct CreateUserDto<'r> {
    #[field(validate = range(2..10))]
    id: usize,
    #[field(validate = email_validation())]
    pub email: &'r str,
    pub password: &'r str,
}
```

And here is the endpoint:

```
#[post("/", data = "<input>")]
fn creart_user(input: Json<CreateUserDto>) {
    let user = input.into_inner();
    println!("email {0}, password: {1}", user.email, user.password);
}
```

In both cases the validation didn't work.

### Update 1:

It seems like the validations are workign when `Form` is applied:

```
#[post("/", data = "<input>")]
fn creart_user(input: Form<CreateUserDto>) {
    let user = input.into_inner();
    println!("email {0}, password: {1}", user.email, user.password);
}
```

Any idea how to run it on `Json` as well?

Comment: debugging and sending invalid value: vvv.com (instead of vv@v.com

Comment: Using a regex to validate an email address is always error prone

Comment: I also tried to create other valisator that failed on any input

Comment: the examples are not complete. But the most basic one is not working :/

Comment: It seems like the validators are not running on Json, only on Form. See updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Rocket implements validation only for forms. As far as I can tell there is no way to trigger validation for other types.

However, you can use a different validation crate. [`validator`](https://docs.rs/validator) seems to be the most popular option, and there is [`rocket-validation`](https://docs.rs/rocket-validation/latest/rocket_validation/) that provides a `rocket` guard for `validator`.